# Json data of a Google Map Engine Lite

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

Is there a correct way to get the json data of a map from Google Map Engine Lite? I know that for maps that are not "lite" I can use the API access but I can't figure out how to access the data in a lite map. I am thinking of scraping the data but wanted to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of right now there is no possible way to extract data from Maps Engine Lite in JSON form.  However there is a free tier on the "platform" (non-Lite) Maps Engine product that will allow API access.  There's more info on the [landing page](http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html).

Comment: Hi Mark. Unfortunately it is not a map I can control. It is map that a client company uploaded and I can't change it to non-Lite. So I guess scraping is my option . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible way just because "lite" version for users who are not developers or programmers, but you can download KML file.